# How can I load a PKCS#11 device in Firefox through a code/script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, smartcard, pkcs#11

I'm trying to automate authentication with smart cards for a web app for which I'm required to use Selenium. When I create a new driver for Firefox, the browser doesn't have the PKCS#11 dll loaded for the smart card I'm using. Is there any way I can add this through a program/script of some sort? I've found a script for the same at http://support.gemalto.com/index.php?id=how_can_register_the_pkcs11, but it's for an older version of Firefox and is not supported anymore.

P.S: I'm using C# as well as PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [modutil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/tools/NSS_Tools_modutil).
Mozilla used to have a [JS API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_crypto), but its going to be removed on next releases.

Comment: Better to put answer in response, rather than links

Comment: Could you please give us the code? I can't configure.

Answer (score 1):

U can use modutil functions in your code and add to secmod.db database.

U can use function as
NSS_Initialize(moduleSpec, "", "", NULL , 0);
where modulespec is path to your secmod.db database.
and then use SECMOD_AddNewModule function to add to database.

Answer (score 0):

There's also https://github.com/open-eid/firefox-pkcs11-loader but this is also among endangered species, because of the removal of the used API-s.